# Can someone see why this nav bar looks different in chrome compared to IE and FF?

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple nav bar which you can see [here](http://deucalion0.co.uk/nav.html). I have no idea why it looks the same in IE and FF but different in Chrome. I am using:

IE 10, FF 20 and Chrome 27.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Gem Training services</title>
<meta name="description" content="Gem training services">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Raymond Leadingham">
<meta name="dcterms.rightsHolder" content="Raymond Leadingham">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1040" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>




<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourexpertise.php">Our Expertise</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourservices.php">Our Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="learningmethods.php">Learning Methods</a></li>
    <li ><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 48px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

#nav li {
    float: left; 
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #1C4688;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #45176E;
    background-color: #fff; 
}


ul li:first-child{
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

There is a little gap at the right of the nav bar in FF and IE, but a bigger gap in Chrome, I have no idea how to style this nav bar so it is the same in all browsers, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: First add a reset stylesheet before your main css - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ Also you have a fixed width on your navigation.

Comment: i saw it, its same in my FF and Chrome its same.  screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#nav {
    width: auto;}
```

or delete width form this class

Comment: I can't believe that fixed it. I had it at 100% then fixed its width, turned out no width is the answer! Thanks a lot, I messed around with this for ages and never tried that :\

Comment: @deucalion0 I would suggest you always **normalize/reset** CSS before you write a single line, browsers behavior is messy enough even when we're sure they _should_ render everything with the same appearance...

Comment: Thanks for the tip Adriano, I do not know what that means or what it does but I will look into using it right now! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

mayt i sure try this completly working in FF, CHROME, IE

```
#nav {
    width: 1000px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

#nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```